# System.Text.Encoding value

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, streamwriter, streamwriter.write

I'm getting an error with the optional argument, it says "Constant expression is required"

How I can resolve the problem?

```
Private Function Write_Text_To_File(ByVal Text_File As String, _
                              ByVal Text As String, _
                              ByVal Append_Text As Boolean, _
                              Optional Encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default) As Boolean

    Try : Using TextFile As New IO.StreamWriter(Text_File, Append_Text, Encoding) : TextFile.WriteLine(Text) : End Using
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Return False
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
```

> UPDATE:

Solution

```
#Region " Write Text to File "

' [ Write Text to File Function ]
'
' // By Elektro H@cker
'
' Examples :
'
' Write_Text_To_File("C:\Test.txt", "Text", False)
' Write_Text_To_File("C:\Test.txt", "Text", True, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

Private Function Write_Text_To_File(ByVal Text_File As String, _
                              ByVal Text As String, _
                              ByVal Append_Text As Boolean, _
                              Optional Encoding As System.Text.Encoding = Nothing) As Boolean
    Try
        If Encoding Is Nothing Then Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
        Using TextFile As New IO.StreamWriter(Text_File, Append_Text, Encoding) : TextFile.WriteLine(Text) : End Using
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Return False
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function

#End Region
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can resolve the problem?

Well, you simply *can't* using `Encoding.Default` as a default parameter value.

What you could do is use `Nothing` as a default parameter value, and simply have:

```
If Encoding Is Nothing Then
    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
End If
```

This does mean you can't use `Nothing` for a different meaning, mind you.

Another alternative would be to just use overloading - provide one version without the encoding parameter which just called the version *with* the encoding parameter, passing in `Encoding.Default`.

Two other points to note:

- Your parameter names don't follow [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002.aspx); they should be camelCased
- `Encoding.Default` is generally a *bad* default to use (and poorly named). Pretty much everything in .NET actually uses `Encoding.UTF8` as the default encoding if you don't specify one; I'd urge you to follow suit.

Comment: Can you give me a example of what means camel casing? I don't speak english and can't translate that word (Google translate it literally as a Camel...)

Comment: @ElektroHacker: Did you try a simple search? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase (And follow the linked documentation for naming conventions.)